# How to resolve "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource"

Tags: reactjs, cors

I am trying to make a fetch request for my React app, but I keep getting this CORS error. The request works fine in Postman. I have added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. I also tried adding mode: 'no-cors', but that did not work either. I can't find anything online for any other solutions. This is the code I'm using:

```
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer <MY_API_KEY>");
    myHeaders.append("Cookie", "__cfduid=db290300ecfe95ec1fe3bc92c388c3c991586618117");
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=Houston", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply looking to validate the Yelp api response then try running the request through a proxy that deals with the CORS policy for you like this:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer <MY_API_KEY>");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "__cfduid=db290300ecfe95ec1fe3bc92c388c3c991586618117");
myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

var proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
var targetUrl = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=Houston'

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};


fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin is **response header**, it's mean that it does not matter in request, the server should allow to you make request.

is it API at yelp.com is allowed to you?